# Why does it show "All subscribers" in a journey builder email send Delivery options area?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have dragged out an email send into my journey but in the tab that manages recipients it shows "Publication List: All Subscribers" at the top. Can someone clarify what this means please. I only want the person passing through the journey to receive the email and this recipient part is confusing me. See screenshot attached.

[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking for "Publication Lists" in the SFMC documentation?

Publications lists are used for managing opt-ins and unsubscribes, they do not define the audience of your send. And if you don't have a specific publication list that you would like to use for a particular send, the [All Subscribers list](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_all_subscribers_list.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) will be used. Here are more details from the documentation:

> **Publication Lists**
>
> A publication list helps you manage how subscribers receive several
> different categories of emails or SMS messages. For example, send
> newsletters, advertisements, and alerts. Each of these is a different
> category, so create a separate publication list for each category.
> When you send a newsletter, associate the send with the newsletter
> publication list to identify to the system what kind of content is
> inside the publication.
>
> Publication lists help you manage subscribers' unsubscribe or opt-out
> actions. Having a separate publication list for each communication
> type enables you to honor an opt-out request from one publication type
> without unsubscribing that person from all previously subscribed-to
> publications. If you use only one publication list for all of a
> subscriber's communications and if that person opts out of one
> publication, that subscriber will be opted out automatically from all
> publications. Additionally:
>
> - Use a publication list to filter the audience of an email send, which    ensures your publications are sent to the subscribers who
>   want to see    them.
> - Use a publication list to show and adhere to regulatory    compliance to CAN-SPAM laws.
> - Use a publication list for each    communication type, such as newsletter, weather alerts, and coupons.
> - Use a publication list to control who receives particular    communications from a company. In Enterprise 2.0, publication lists
>   can be shared between parent and child business units.

[image]

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5